What's the distinction between an elliptic curve and its rational points?
I'm confused by this statement:
"Be careful that you understand the distinction between the elliptic curve E and the group E(k) of its k-rational points. The group law is defined for the curve E, not just the points in E(k)." (from here).
To my understanding, an elliptic $E$ curve is defined by a cubic equation with coefficients in some field $F$.  I see that field extensions $F \subset K$ define subgroups $E(F) \subset E(K)$, and that identifying "the curve" with rational points over any particular field would ignore that.  But what precisely is meant by "the curve $E$"? Is $E$ to be understood as something more than $E(F)$? Perhaps as $E(\bar{F})$?

In the classical context you are probably considering (i.e. not using scheme theory) algebraic geometry is generally done over an algebraically closed field, since things like the Weak Nullstellensatz fail otherwise. Right now it is probably best to interpret "the curve $E$" as referring to all points satisfying the cubic equation over the algebraic closure $\overline{k}$, sitting inside the projective space $\mathbb{P}^2_{\overline{k}}$. Then $E(k)$ is the subset of $E$ consisting of points with all coordinates lying in $k$ under some choice of homogeneous coordinates.
This framework is still adequate to study elliptic curves, e.g. from the texts of Silverman, but I should caution you that this is not the modern perspective of what the curve $E$ "is". The modern approach is to treat $E$ as a scheme, where the notion of "what $E$ is" vs. "points on $E$" is totally revamped.
